# What is the pythonic approach to pass and return list in a function?

Tags: python

```
lst=[1,2,3]

def fn(lst):
  lst.append(100)
  return lst

fn(lst) # x = fn(lst)
print(lst) # print(x)
```

In the above example, since list is passed by assignment, the append is visible to the lst outside the function also.

Is it pythonic to:

1. Return a list as shown in the example.
2. Not return since it is obvious that lst outside the fn has got the append?
3. Is there any other pythonic way - like to pass a copy of list and then return seems logical.
4. Return none?

Comment: Ask yourself this: why doesn't `lst.append` itself return the list? The standard idiom in Python is to *either* mutate the argument and return `None`, or to create a new modified version of the argument and return it, leaving the argument unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Since the list is passed by assignment" is not quite correct.  Everything is passed by reference to the Python object: every datum in Python is an object.  In this case, you passed a mutable object and used `append` to modify the object in place.  There is no need to `return` a value.

You need to decide whether your function should modify in place, or return a new object.  You have done both, which confuses the user interface.  This is far better than doing *neither* (we've had a few of those questions), but you should do only one or the other.

In-place change:

```
def fn(lst):
    lst.append(100)
```

Return new list, leaving the original unchanged:

```
def fn(lst):
    new_list = lst[:]
    return new_list + [100]
```

Comment: Suppose my list is huge, then am I right in assuming that in term of memory efficiency, the inplace option is preferreable?

Comment: You're incorrect to assume anything with considering the system design.  "preferable" is entirely dependent on the use cases for your function.

Comment: Regarding your last example, how about invoking the function by passing a copy? Example - fn(lst.copy())

Comment: How about it?  When you tried it, did it work as needed?

Comment: Yes it worked with copy approach using list slicing. But just thinking if that's proper pythonic

Comment: As a general principle, no: you're placing an additional requirement on the user for no benefit.  If the function requires a copy, then the function should create it.  If the function is to alter the user's original, then supplying a copy would negate the function's operation.